# Baby dragon doesn't eat many roaches

Tags: feeding, bearded-dragon

My baby (2-3 months) bearded dragon only eats about 6-9 dubia roaches a day. I add dehydrated meal worms to "her" (still not totally sure yet) salad every day. Is this normal behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How much does she weigh?
Can you tell me about your setup (temps, humidity, substrate etc.)
How much weight is she gaining every week?
Is she eating her veggies?

If the dubia roaches are large they could just be filling her up much faster than small crickets.

Comment: I just started to weigh her this week, due to my concerns, so I don't have enough data yet on this front. Set up: Basking temps-D105, N95; Cool end temps-D85, N75; Humidity is 40 to 50%; UV lamp- ExoTerra Repti-glo 10.0; Substrate: vinyl tile; Bath: W, Sn; Food dusted M,W,F,Sn with Cal+D3 and Multivitamins; Dusted T, Th, St with just Cal(no D3); Veg this week: bok choy, endive, kale, and carrots. Fruit offered Sn. Up until today I had been offering the roaches 3x a day, 5-6 per offering and she has been eating 2 each time. Plans to offer 4 crickets tonight as well to see if it is pref.

Comment: Temps are good, I would however switch your UVB light. Sunglo emit very little UVB, I highly recommend going for a mercury vapor bulb. These lights blast out UV lighting which, for beardies, is fantastic.
Another good lighting source are the tube lights as well, coil bulbs in general should be avoided.

For powders you will not need to add the D3 once you switch on over to a MVB, large amounts of oral D3 can be toxic. Once that is switched over stick to calcium every other day and multivitamin once a week.

Comment: ~continuation~

If the dubia roaches are large they could just be filling her up much faster than small crickets.

How often is she having a bowel movement?

As a side note, I've tried tile before and the amount of sludge that accumulated under there was awful. Keep a note to check under the tiles during the cleanings :)

Comment: In switching to an MVB, do I just ditch the standard basking light? And will this give sufficient light for the entire tank? Also, you might be right about the roaches being bigger... this morning I put both roaches and crickets in her feeding bin and she went for the roaches first.

Comment: Not necessarily, in the winter time I need to use my MVB plus a basking bulb to keep good temperatures. In the summer I use my MVB basking bulb and the temps stay in the 95F +. Feel free to post a picture of your setup.